# I have a csv file with time as the datetime format and want to edit the same column into miliseconds, how do I change that?

Tags: python, csv

Input file is :

```
time    event   earthAcceleration.x earthAcceleration.y earthAcceleration.z             
2017-11-22T09:20:13.944 motion  -0.006379993    -0.001029071 -0.010781396   
2017-11-22T09:20:13.954 motion  0.014739769 0.008146121 -0.001068155                
2017-11-22T09:20:13.964 motion  0.008520941 -0.008222823    0.022573506             
2017-11-22T09:20:13.974 motion  0.000573836 0.016701656 -0.016170829                
2017-11-22T09:20:13.984 motion  0.016282924 0.003181049 0.006969224
```

I need to remove the date and hours and just need the milliseconds from the start. Example: `Time2 = time2-time1` i.e. I need relative time in milliseconds such that I can plot a graph by time.

Output:
(the time column should change into)

```
time
0.00
0.15
1.12
1.34
```

Answer (score 1):

Familiarize yourself with the pandas library, which allows you to do this:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from io import StringIO
csv_file = StringIO("""time event earthAcceleration.x earthAcceleration.y earthAcceleration.z
2017-11-22T09:20:13.944 motion -0.006379993 -0.001029071 -0.010781396
2017-11-22T09:20:13.954 motion 0.014739769 0.008146121 -0.001068155
2017-11-22T09:20:13.964 motion 0.008520941 -0.008222823 0.022573506
2017-11-22T09:20:13.974 motion 0.000573836 0.016701656 -0.016170829
2017-11-22T09:20:13.984 motion 0.016282924 0.003181049 0.006969224""")
df = read_csv(csv_file, sep=' ', parse_dates=['time'])
df.assign(delta_t = df.time-df.time.ix[0])
```

I believe your output is wrong; the difference between each line is exactly 0.01s. Welcome to the site!

Comment: I did this code but it does not change my file and doess not get the desired ouput

Comment: Hey, You wrote each column but I have hundreds of columns how do I do it?

Comment: What do you mean? I just simulated the csv file by using StringIO; you will skip that step and feed read_csv your actual file.

Comment: from pandas import read_csv
from io import StringIO
csv_file = open("test.csv', 'a')
df = read_csv(csv_file, sep=' ', parse_dates=['time'])
df.assign(delta_t = df.time-df.time.iloc[0])

Comment: I did this but nothing changed

Comment: I just have to replace the whole string you wrote by the code " csv_file = open('test.csv' ,'a') right?

Comment: Try passing the file name to read_csv instead of a file object. Notice we are not saving the result in the last line, so you might want to assign it to a new variable or re-assign to df. For documentation see http://pandas.pydata.org. Here are two MOOCs: [edx](https://www.edx.org/course/python-data-science-uc-san-diegox-dse200x), [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-data-analysis)

Comment: How do I ignore the blanks in my file? i think because of no value it is giivng me error

Comment: Try the [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) method. In the future take such questions to StackOverflow; they do not belong here, and you will get a faster response there.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but I cant post the question there due to my profile being so new. thanks for the help!